# Fields not showing in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I have the following dynamic stored procedure which returns a normal result set at the end however crystal reports is not returning any fields along with it might anyone have an idea what is wrong.

When I run the proc in studio management it works fine. This is a report using the sap version of crystal in case that makes a difference.

I would normally output the results to excel and it runs correctly but for crystal its not allowing me to select any fields in the field explorer.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportByDates]

       @DateFrom date NULL,
       @DateTo date NULL
AS            

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @DynamicColumnsDivision AS VARCHAR(max)  
DECLARE @DynamicColumnsDivision2 AS VARCHAR(max)  
DECLARE @DynamicColumnsDivisionTotal AS VARCHAR(max)  
SELECT @DynamicColumnsDivision = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsDivision + ', ', '')  
+ 'ISNULL(' +Quotename(fieldname) + ',0) as ' + Quotename(fieldname) 
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'Division'
) AS FieldList  





SELECT @DynamicColumnsDivision2 = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsDivision2 + ', ', '')  
+ Quotename(fieldname)
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'Division'

) AS FieldList 


SELECT @DynamicColumnsDivisionTotal = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsDivisionTotal + '+', '')  
+ 'ISNULL(' +Quotename(fieldname) + ',0)' 
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'Division'
) AS FieldList  


DECLARE @DynamicColumnsGQO AS VARCHAR(max)  
DECLARE @DynamicColumnsGQO2 AS VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @DynamicColumnsGQOTotal as VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @DynamicColumnsGQO = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsGQO + ', ', '')  
+ 'ISNULL(' +Quotename(fieldname) + ',0) as ' + Quotename(fieldname) 
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'GQO'
) AS FieldList  





SELECT @DynamicColumnsGQO2 = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsGQO2 + ', ', '')  
+ Quotename(fieldname)
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'GQO'

) AS FieldList 

SELECT @DynamicColumnsGQOTotal = COALESCE(@DynamicColumnsGQOTotal + '+', '')  
+ 'ISNULL(' +Quotename(fieldname) + ',0)' 
FROM (

SELECT 
DISTINCT
PrcCode + ' - ' + cc.PrcName as fieldname

FROM OPRC cc 
WHERE Active = 'Y' AND CCTypeCode = 'GQO'
) AS FieldList  

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query = 
'SELECT Account, AcctName, ' + @DynamicColumnsDivision + ', ' + @DynamicColumnsDivisionTotal + ' as DivisionTotal , ' + @DynamicColumnsGQO + ', ' + @DynamicColumnsGQOTotal + ' as GQOToatl
FROM
(
SELECT 
line.Account,
nom.AcctName,
line.ProfitCode + '' - '' + cc.PrcName as fieldname,
CASE WHEN line.Debit <> 0 THEN line.Debit *-1 WHEN line.Credit <> 0 THEN line.Credit  ELSE 0 END as DispValue
FROM OJDT head
LEFT JOIN  JDT1 line on head.TransId = line.TransId
LEFT JOIN OACT nom on line.Account = nom.AcctCode
LEFT JOIN OPRC cc ON line.ProfitCode = cc.PrcCode
WHERE head.RefDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateFrom, 101) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateTo, 101) + '''
) AS SourceTable PIVOT
(
SUM(DispValue)
FOR fieldname IN (' + @DynamicColumnsDivision2 + ', '+@DynamicColumnsGQO2 + ')
) AS PivotTable;

'
--SELECT @Query
execute(@Query)
```

**Edit 2**
Weird I copied the entire proc and declared the date from and date to elements and it worked fine. So why when it being called from a stored proc is it working ok.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure does not return any data Crystal Reports won't be able to show you the columns. Make sure it returns the data.

Anyways, you can always try to remove the stored procedure and add it again in the database assistant. Crystal Reports is not very good updating the fields when you use a stored procedure, or at least it wasn't in older versions.

Comment: Ander it returns data fine, I stated it works in managment studio

Comment: Did it return data when you first designed the report in crystal reports. I have tried it in SAP Crystal Reports and it's working fine. Try to remove the stored procedure and add it again.

Comment: Weirdest thing is we dumped the stored procedure without paramters and delcaired variables however it returned the fields it doesnt return data unless parameters are entered any ideas.